# После установки CentOS 7 появилось много пунктов при загрузке ОС

Tags: linux, centos

Почему-то после установки CentOS 7 в меню загрузки появилось еще 2 лишних пункта?

Причем один из них просто загружает систему, а другой вообще непонятно что делает.

Как убрать лишние элементы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это не лишние элементы , выбирайте Первый в списке

Comment: Первый в списке просто перезагружает пк, второй и третий загружают centos

Comment: просто сначала их было два, недавно стало три. мне кажется это странным

Comment: Странно у меня с первого пункта загружается ОС

Comment: Да, у меня тоже так было, не знаю то ли из-за обновления, то ли из-за чего, но у меня появился еще один элемент и он просто перезагружает пк и работает по-умолчанию. Поэтому если вовремя не выбрать второй пункт, то произойдет просто перезагрузка. А если просто оставить комп включенным, то он будет бесконечно перезагружаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

судя по заголовкам, третий пункт служит для загрузки в [режиме восстановления (rescue)](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-rescuemode-boot.html).

первый же и второй пункт отличаются, скорее всего, лишь тем, какая версия программы *linux* будет загружена (1).

хотя могут быть и иные отличия. вы можете их исследовать, перейдя к редактированию выбранного пункта, нажав (обычно) `e` (смотрите текст подсказки внизу экрана).

---

(1) пакеты, содержащие разные версии программы *linux*, называются в дистрибутиве *centos* операционной системы *gnu/linux*, скорее всего так: `kernel-номер_версии`. посмотреть список установленных пакетов можно, например, так (приведён и пример вывода):

```
$ rpm -qa | grep '^kernel-[0-9]'
kernel-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64
```

можете удалить неиспользуемые пакеты:

```
$ sudo yum remove название_пакета
```

если же пакета с той версией программы *linux*, что упомянута в первой строчке на приведённом вами снимке экрана, в системе нет, то (если других систем в компьютере не установлено), это, вероятно, исправится после обновления конфигурации программы *grub*. согласно [этому ответу](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152235/110559), для этого надо запустить:

```
$ sudo new-kernel-pkg
```

Comment: `$ rpm -qa | grep '^kernel-[0-9]'`
выдает

`kernel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64`

не могу разобраться как удалить через new-kernel-pkg

`new-kernel-pkg --remove kernel-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64`  ничего не выдает

Comment: это имя пакета. удалить пакет можно, например, командой `sudo yum remove имя_пакета` (команда приведена в ответе).

Comment: работает) но теперь когда я делаю апдейт мне предлагается скачать этот же пакет, можно ли при апдейте игнорировать его?

Comment: @yutsura, можно, игнорируйте. шутка. вы удалили более новую версию пакета `kernel`. потому вам и предлагается его обновить. обновите, перезагрузитесь, проверьте, что более новая версия программы linux нормально загружается, и удалите более старую версию пакета.

Comment: так вот эта новая версия как раз просто перезагружала систему